# Explicit template specialization cannot have a storage class - member method specialization

Tags: c++

Say I have the following code in Visual Studio

```
class foo
{
public:
    template<typename t>
    void foo_temp(int a , t s_)
    {
        std::cout << "This is general tmeplate method";
    }

    template<>
    static void foo_temp(int a , int s)
    {
        std::cout << "This is a specialized method";
    }
};


int main()
{
    foo f;
    f.foo_temp<std::string>(12,"string");
}
```

Now I am attempting to covert this into GCC. Going through other questions on SO I noticed that in GCC member methods cannot be specialized if the class is not specialized. I therefore came up with this solution

```
class foo
{

    public:
    template<typename t>
    void foo_temp(int a , t s_)
    {
        std::cout << "This is general template method";
    }


};

template <>
/*static*/ void foo::foo_temp<int>(int a, int value) {
    std::cout << "Hello world";
}
```

Now this seems to do the trick however when I include the static keyword into the statement i get the error

```
 explicit template specialization cannot have a storage class
```

Now [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041775/explicit-template-specialization-cannot-have-a-storage-class-member-method-spe) thread talks about it but I am still confused on how I could apply that here. Any suggestions on how I can make the last method static ? Also I am still confused as to why templated methods cant be static in GCC ?

This is the visual studio code

```
class foo
{
public:
    template<typename t>
    void foo_temp(int a , t s_)
    {
        std::cout << "This is general tmeplate method";
    }

    template<>
    static void foo_temp(int a , int s)
    {
        std::cout << "This is a specialized method";
    }
};


int main()
{
    foo f;
    f.foo_temp<std::string>(12,"string");
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am porting a code which is not as simple as the one I have put up.

Comment: Seriously, that original code compiled in MSVC??!! I know its template engine is badly nonconforming, but that's a new low.

Comment: *GCC member methods cannot be specialized if the class is not specialized* - how does that apply here? Your class is not even a template. The error in the first example is that explicit specializations must occur at namespace scope. If you want `foo_temp` to be a static member function, then add `static` to the primary member function template.

Comment: Ill put the VS code up too

Comment: @JamesFranco, that didn't really answer the question.  Why was this code written in this manner to begin with?  What problem are you trying to solve?  Why do you need a static method?  Why won't overloading work?  And so on.  The answer to your question is that what you're trying to do seems nonsensical and not actually supported by the language, and it's only because VS has terrible template handling that it ever worked in the first place, but that's not very helpful to you.  So I'm trying to be helpful by getting more context.

Comment: @T.C. Yep, no complaints at all from VS2013. I added `foo::foo_temp(12,12);` to `main()` and still nothing. Even the second snippet is accepted, `static` and all, but then I have to call it as `f.foo_temp(12,12);`

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I am porting a pretty big codebase from visual studio to GCC. I am not totally sure about the working of the particular component but it resembled something like the VS code I put up. The code i put up is a very simplified form of the problem that I am trying to overcome.

Comment: @Praetorian Wow. Just wow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any suggestions on how I can make the last method static?

You can't; it's unsupported by the language.

> Also I am still confused as to why templated methods cant be static in GCC?

They can; they just can't be both static and non-static.  Example:

```
struct foo {
  template<typename T>
  void bar() {}

  template<typename T>
  static void baz() {}
};

int main() {
  foo f;
  f.template bar<void>();
  foo::baz<void>();
}
```

It's very confusing to me why you must have a static specialization of a (non-static) template member function.  I would seriously re-evaluate this code for sanity.

Note, to the question in the comments, it is not possible to have a template specialization of a static member function, because it is not possible to have a template specialization of a member function in this situation at all.  (Use overloading instead.)

```
struct foo {
  template<typename T, typename U>
  static void bar(T, U) {}

  // Error, you'd need to also specialize the class, which requires a template class, we don't have one.
  // template<>
  // static void bar(int, int) {}
  // test.cpp:2:12: error: explicit specialization of non-template ‘foo’
  //     2 | struct foo {
  //       |            ^
  
  // Partial specializations aren't allowed even in situations where full ones are
  // template<typename U>
  // static void bar<int, U>(int, U) {}
  // test.cpp:14:33: error: non-class, non-variable partial specialization ‘bar<int, U>’ is not allowed
  //   14 |   static void bar<int, U>(int, U) {}
  //      |                                 ^

  // Instead just overload
  template<typename U>
  static void bar(int, U) {}
};
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why it would be a bad idea to specialize a static method. I'm hitting a similar issue, where my utilities are in a static class and I want to specialize one of them with a certain type that wouldn't work with the non-specialized method. Sure, namespaces or constexpr ifs will provide the workaround, but still, specialization would be cleaner... ?

Comment: It's an opinion, and I think I stated it a bit forcefully 5 years ago.  But I still think it's a bad idea.  The point of templates is to have a uniform API for a class regardless of type.  If you have a version of the class that has the same function but with a different API based on type, that gets confusing and undercuts the usefulness of the template.  That being said, there's also a technical reason why this doesn't occur, and it has to do with how member functions are implemented internally.  A non-static member function gets passed as its first argument the instance, the static does not.

Comment: I've updated the answer to maybe address your question a bit better @NormanPellet

Comment: Ah yes, fair enough ! I always forget this pretty strict limitation of member function specialization.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707184/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope-does-not-compile-in-gcc

Comment: @IceflowerS I'm unsure what the point of that link is.  If it's about the second part, specialization of the template function, you need to templatize the class, which is the difference between the situation here and there.  I mention that in one of the comments.

Answer (score 3):

The static method isn't the problem here, the `template<>` declaration inside a class is the main culprit. You can't declare specialized template inside a class. you can use namespace instead:

```
namespace foo{

        template<typename t>
        void foo_temp(int a , t s_)
        {
            std::cout << "This is general tmeplate method";
        }
        template<>
          void foo_temp(int a , int s)
        {
            std::cout << "This is a specialized method";
        }

    }




    int main()
    {

        foo::foo_temp<int>(12,7);
    }
```

Or you can use it inside class like this:

```
class foo
{
public:
    template<typename t>
    void foo_temp(int a , t s_)
    {
        std::cout << "This is general tmeplate method";
    }


    static void foo_temp(int a , int s)
    {
        std::cout << "This is a specialized method";
    }
};


int main()
{
    foo f;
    f.foo_temp(12,"string");
    f.foo_temp(12,6);
}
```

N.B: you should call both function (at least the second one) like `f.foo_temp(a,b)` instead of `f.foo_temp<int>()` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try good old fashioned overloading? Don't make the static method a template at all and let overloading priority take care of picking it.