# Explicit specialization in non-namespace scope does not compile in GCC

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, language-lawyer, bug-reporting

The following code compiles in Clang but does not in GCC:

```
template<typename T>
struct Widget
{
    template<typename U>
    void foo(U)
    {
    }

    template<>
    void foo(int*)
    {
    }
};
```

According to the C++ standard ([temp.expl.spec], paragraph 2):

> An explicit specialization may be declared in any scope in which the corresponding primary template may be
>   defined

Is this a bug in GCC and if so how can I find it in its bug tracker?

This is GCC's output:

```
prog.cc:13:14: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'struct Widget<T>'
     template<>
              ^
```

I'm using GCC HEAD 8.0.1, with `-std=c++2a`.

Answer (score 37):

This should be a GCC bug. Full specialization should be allowed in any scope, including in class definition.

According to [CWG 727](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#727), [temp.expl.spec] paragraph 2 was changed from

(emphasis mine)

> An explicit specialization **shall be declared in a namespace** enclosing the specialized template. An explicit specialization whose declarator-id or class-head-name is not qualified shall be declared in the nearest enclosing namespace of the template, or, if the namespace is inline (10.3.1 [namespace.def]), any namespace from its enclosing namespace set. Such a declaration may also be a definition. If the declaration is not a definition, the specialization may be defined later (10.3.1.2 [namespace.memdef]).

to

(emphasis mine)

> An explicit specialization **may be declared in any scope** in which the corresponding primary template may be defined (10.3.1.2 [namespace.memdef], 12.2 [class.mem], 17.6.2 [temp.mem]).

It seems GCC fails to follow this.

**EDIT**

I have reported the issue as [Bug 85282](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85282).

Comment: This is a big change, no need any more of the defaulted dumb template parameter trick to simulate a an explicit template specialization :)!!

Comment: Can you clarify which standard changes that? C++17?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes it's changed since C++17. You may check the different description in C++14(draft N4140) and C++17(draft N4659).

Comment: @songyuanyao No, not really. The defect report has been retroactively applied to C++14.

Comment: Great reference!   After some testing, I found that Clang C++17 still does not allow it.   Evidence : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4477a9354f6cba2d  Do you have any idea?  Thank.

Comment: @cppBeginner You meant Gcc?

Comment: I am not sure.  I notice both "clang++" and "g++" in the bottom of the coliru web page.  I am new to this stuff.  Thank.

Comment: @cppBeginner I think Gcc is used; and yes, Gcc still doesn't fix this issue; [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/R3dM6pQpsNR5IWje) works fine.

Comment: So far, this does not seem fixed and gcc dev claims that cwg727 never was approved.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: No one has claimed that—only that it shouldn’t be allowed in language modes prior to `-std=c++17`.  That said, I think *that’s* in error.

Comment: @DavisHerring some compiler supported it for ages..at work I work with one from 2009 and it got C++17\C++14 features for templates or lambdas, like this syntax, but doesn't support variadic templates or range-based for!

Comment: @Oliv, how does the "dumb template parameter trick" work?

Comment: @fde-capu Partial specialization was allowed. So let's say you declared a template with `template <typename P1> class X`, if you wanted to provide a specialization for X you could change the declaration to `template <typename P1, typename Dumb = void> class X` and then provide a partial specialization `template<typename Dumb> class X<Int, Dumb>`

Answer (score 10):

If somebody is looking for a workaround till this is fixed in gcc:

It is possible to use `std::is_same_v` and `if constexpr`
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hzdzG4s5P)

```
template<typename T>
struct Widget
{
    template<typename U>
    void foo(U)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<U, int*>) {
            std::cout << "int*\n";
        }
        std::cout << "U\n";
    }

};
```

Comment: Thanks for this one. Seems to be the only one which works for member functions! :)
Ugly if a lot of types are needed but still better to move all the code outside the class and add extra declarations.