# Why a fully specialized class template can't be defined in a non-fully specialized one?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization, partial-specialization

Why a fully specialized class template can't be defined in a non-fully specialized one?

```
template<typename TW>
struct Wrapper {
    template<typename T>
    struct Fun_ {
        constexpr static int vlaue = 0;
    };
    template<> // error
    struct Fun_<int> { // error
        constexpr static int value = 1;
    };
};

int main() {
}
```

GCC version:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
```

GCC error:

```
test.cpp:7:14: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘struct Wrapper<TW>’
     template<>
              ^
test.cpp:8:12: error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:
     struct Fun_<int> {
            ^
```

Clang version:

```
clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2~16.04.1 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Clang error:

```
test.cpp:8:12: error: explicit specialization of 'Fun_' in class
      scope
    struct Fun_<int> {
           ^
```

---

However, by converting the fully specialized class template into a partially specialized one using an additional pseudo template argument, the following can compile:

```
template<typename TW>
struct Wrapper {
    // TDummy is a pseudo template argument with default value void
    template<typename T, typename TDummy = void>
    struct Fun_ {
        constexpr static int value = 0;
    };
    template<typename TDummy>
    struct Fun_<int, TDummy> { // partial specialization
        constexpr static int value = 1;
    };
};

int main() {
}
```

Comment: What compiler is being used? VC++ is (or at least used to be) non-compliant in that regard and required explicit specializations to be at namespace level; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052579/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope

Comment: I confirm your problem (in first example) with g++ (wandbox) but clang++ compile without problem. A bug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explicit specialization in non-namespace scope does not compile in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707184/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope-does-not-compile-in-gcc)

Comment: @max66 - clang is right; in c++17 this is possible. See the duplicate link.

Comment: @max66 However my Clang get the error, even in C++17? What's the version do you use?

Comment: @Jans However my Clang get the error, even in C++17? What's the version do you use?