# Specialize member functions based on size of member container

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I have a class that holds some statically-sized containers:

```
template <typename Container>
struct Point {
    Container container;
    ... 
    void bar();
}
```

where a `Container` class might look like:

```
struct Container1 {
    static constexpr size_t size = 5;
}
```

Now I want to specialize the `bar` method based on the size of the container. I do not understand how to do that.

EDIT:

I would like a C++11 solution. C++14 might work, but the compilers we work with typically have spotty C++14 support.

EDIT:

Stack Danny suggested a solution which compiles with Clang, but not with GCC.

Comment: Since C++17, by `if constexpr` (if the signature should not change. OT: `bar();` is not a valid function declaration and `contexpr` is not a keyword.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention C++11

Comment: It is kind of surprising to me that that was only introduced in C++17.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of specialisation, use SFINAE

```
template <typename Container>
class Point {
    Container container;
    template<size_t S> std::enable_if_t<S==3>
    bar_t() { std::cout << "specialisation for size=3\n"; }
    template<size_t S> std::enable_if_t<S==5>
    bar_t() { std::cout << "specialisation for size=5\n"; }
    template<size_t S> std::enable_if_t<S==42>
    bar_t() { std::cout << "specialisation for size=42\n"; }
  public:
    void bar()
    { bar_t<Container::size>(); }
};
```

`std::enable_if_t` is C++14, but you can trivially declare it yourself:

```
#if __cplusplus < 201402L
template<bool C, typename T=void>
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<C,T>::type;
#endif
```

Btw, your question smells like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): do you really need to specialize `bar()` for the `Container::size`? In the following example, a loop is unrolled for any size `N`.

```
template<typename scalar, size_t N>
class point // a point in R^N
{
    scalar array[N];
  public:
    // multiplication with scalar
    point& operator*=(scalar x) noexcept
    {
        // unroll loop using template meta programming
        loop([array,x](size_t i) { array[i] *= x; };);
        /* alternatively: rely on the compiler to do it
        for(size_t i=0; i!=N; ++i)
            array[i] *= x;
        */
        return *this;   
    }
  private:
    template<size_t I=0, typename Lambda>
    static enable_if_t<(I<N)> loop(Lambda &&lambda)            
    {
        lambda(I);
        loop<I+1>(lambda);
    }
    template<size_t I=0, typename Lambda>
    static enable_if_t<(I>=N)> loop(Lambda &&)         {}
};
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is there an easier way to have a default other than AND-ing all the complements?

Answer (score 4):

It is called template specialization and works as follows:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
    
struct Container1 {
    static constexpr size_t size = 5;
};
struct Container2 {
    static constexpr size_t size = 3;
};
    
    
template <typename Container>
struct Point {
    Container container;
    
    void bar() {
        this->bar_templated<Container::size>();
    }
    
private:
    template<std::size_t size>
    void bar_templated() {
        std::cout << "default\n";
    }
    template<>
    void bar_templated<3>() {
        std::cout << "specialized <3>\n";
    }
    template<>
    void bar_templated<5>() {
        std::cout << "specialized <5>\n";
    }
};
    
int main(){
    Point<Container1> p1;
    p1.bar();
    Point<Container2> p2;
    p2.bar();
}
```

**output**

```
specialized <5>
specialized <3>
```

due to [bug 85282](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85282) in gcc making it [impossible to compile an explicit specialization in non-namespace scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707184/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope-does-not-compile-in-gcc) (thanks @songyuanyao), there are errors:

> 25:14: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'struct Point'
>
> 26:27: error: template-id 'bar_templated<3>' in declaration of primary template
>
> ...
>
> 30:10: error: 'void Point::bar_templated()' cannot be overloaded

But you can workaround this by moving the functions out of the class and still achieve specialization:

```
template<std::size_t size>
void bar_templated() {
    std::cout << "default\n";
}
template<>
void bar_templated<3>() {
    std::cout << "specialized 3\n";
}
template<>
void bar_templated<5>() {
    std::cout << "specialized 5\n";
}


template <typename Container>
struct Point {
    Container container;

    void bar() {
        bar_templated<Container::size>();
    }
};
```

This way the functions are public, which may not be what you want, though. Well, if you're writing inside a header file you could define them inside an anonymous namespace.

---

Also: [if constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) - but that's only C++17 and forward. It reducing the code size by alot and keeping it's logical nature makes it the best approach here, for sure.

```
void bar() {
    if constexpr (Container::size == 3) {
        std::cout << "specialized <3>\n";
    }
    else if constexpr (Container::size == 5) {
        std::cout << "specialized <5>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this but I was getting errors indicating that you could not specialize a template function in a template class. Trying again now.

Comment: That only seems to work in Clang. GCC 8.2 can't compile that.

Comment: Is there any fix to make it compile with GCC?

Comment: I used Visual Studio so neither of the two compilers. Weird that gcc doesn't compile this. I try to look for another strategy

Comment: Curious: What does C++ standard say? Is this a feature GCC left unimplemented or a compiler extension of clang and MSVC?

Comment: @Aconcagua [Explicit specialization in non-namespace scope does not compile in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49707184/3309790)

Answer (score 2):

You can apply template overloading with [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

```
template <typename C = Container>
auto bar() -> typename std::enable_if<C::size==5>::type { ... }
template <typename C = Container>
auto bar() -> typename std::enable_if<C::size==42>::type { ... }
... ...
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kJ4o2hOkpX5PCbyE)

Comment: I think `bar()` is not supposed to be a `template`.

Comment: Well, from the OP, `bar()` is not a template. Don't ask me why, ask bremen_matt.

Comment: @Walter Yes I know that, I meant, what might be the potential problem if make it a template?

Comment: @Walter Sorry can't get what you mean.. Did you see the live sample I posted?

Comment: Ah, okay. I missed that you had a default template parameter.