# Explicit specialization in class: difference between Clang and GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, c++20, explicit-specialization

The code below compiles and works correctly in Clang but in GCC it gives an error:

`<source>:9:14: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class DecideType<A, B>'`

```
template<int A, int B> class DecideType
{
    template<bool CONDITION = A < B> class RealDecision
    {
    public:
        using type = int;
    };

    template<> class RealDecision<false>
    {
    public:
        using type = char;
    };

public:
    using type = typename RealDecision<>::type;
};
```

The code can be fixed for GCC very easily by just adding some additional, unused template parameter.

```
template<int A, int B> class DecideType
{
    template<class X, bool CONDITION = A < B> class RealDecision
    {
    public:
        using type = int;
    };

    template<class X> class RealDecision<X, false>
    {
    public:
        using type = char;
    };

public:
    using type = typename RealDecision<void>::type;
};
```

Which compiler is correct and why?
I've found a change proposal that would suggest that a full specialization should be allowed in this situation since C++17 but I don't know if this is officially in the standard. https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue727

If GCC is right, why there is such a difference between partial specialization and explicit specialization?
After all, explicit specialization is just special case of partial specialization.

### EDIT 0

There is a bug report for C++17 https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85282. I think it is rejected but it seems to be pretty inconclusive with my knowledge. I don't know if it allows to conclude anything about C++20.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052579/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope#:~:text=An%20explicit%20specialization%20shall%20be,class%20template%20is%20a%20member. ?

Comment: An explicit specialization isn’t a template, in your case it’s a class, while the partial specialization is a template.

Comment: @Dani Isn't an empty array an array? I would be tempted to say that any non-template type is a template with 0 parameters ;)

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Not exactly. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49707184/3052438 is closer but it's still is a little too old. I'm looking for an answer for C++20 because there is a good chance that the situation has changed in this version.

Comment: @NO_NAME: Nothing has changed in C++ or (unfortunately) GCC since that question was asked; this is a duplicate unless you really want the two-word answer “no news”.

Comment: @DavisHerring Well, it's still a better answer than no answer. I understand you've confirmed this with the ISO standard?

Comment: @NO_NAME: The default for anything is “nothing has changed”—we wouldn’t want “Does C++20 still have `decltype`?” as a question, so I’m not too sure about this one.  The wording changed in the issue is still present in C++20, yes.

Comment: @DavisHerring Well, if they were debates about removing `decltype` in the international standardization organization, then perhaps we would want that question. Anyway, that answer satisfy me.

Comment: @NO_NAME: There have been no debates about this question either since March 2017.

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes. You would expect that any decision from 2017 could made into C++20. C++17 was already finalizing.

Comment: @NO_NAME: But the issue page that you linked gives it a status of “C++17”, and no one has suggested that it wasn’t included.