# Specialization of templated method in a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, class-template

I have a simple template class with a template method in it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

template <typename T>
class Test
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    std::optional<U> test() { return std::nullopt; }

    std::optional<double> test() { return std::make_optional<double>(3.0); }
};

int main()
{
    Test<int> t;
    std::cout << t.test<int>().value_or(100) << " " << t.test<double>().value_or(100) << std::endl;
}
```

I'd like the program to print `100 3.0` or `100 3` rather than `100 100`. How do I specialize the `test` method within `Test` such that it returns a non-empty optional with value `3.0`?

In addition to the above, I've tried to add `template<>` above the specialization. This results in a compiler error (running `gcc -std=c++17 test.cpp` with GCC 9.4.0):

```
test.cpp:11:14: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘class Test<T>’
   11 |     template<>
      |
```

Comment: What you have above is not a specialization but an overload. You cannot specialize a member template without also specializing its enclosing class.

Comment: This is a well known [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85282). Dupe: [Explicit specialization in non-namespace scope does not compile in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707184/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope-does-not-compile-in-gcc)

Comment: @user12002570 It is not that bug. Try moving the specialization out of the class scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can specialize `test` for `double` in the following way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

template <typename T>
class Test
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    std::optional<U> test() { return std::nullopt; }

    // Specialization for double:
    template <>
    std::optional<double> test() { return std::make_optional<double>(3.0); }
};

int main()
{
    Test<int> t;
    std::cout << t.test<int>().value_or(100) << " " << t.test<double>().value_or(100) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
100 3
```

---

Update:
This solution works for MSVC, but not for GCC. See more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097811/c-syntax-for-explicit-specialization-of-a-template-function-in-a-template-clas), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707184/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope-does-not-compile-in-gcc).
A possible workaround for GCC is to use `if constexpr` instead of a specialization:

```
template <typename T>
class Test
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    std::optional<U> test() 
    { 
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<U, double>)
        {
            return std::make_optional<double>(3.0);
        }
        return std::nullopt; 
    }
};
```

Comment: What compiler command and version are you using?

Comment: VisualStudio 2022 (MSVC)

Comment: I now see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052579/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope), which means MSVC is non-standard in this case ...

Comment: @wohlstad The standard has been fixed (but GCC was not). Explicit specialization is allowed at any scope a primary template definition is allowed. However an explicit specialization of a member of an unspecialized template doesn't seem to be legal (the standard is not very clear about this).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I see. I guess the `if constexpr` workaround is better then, in terms of complying with the standard.